# Count number of bytes of all gzip files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that needs to know the count of bytes for all gzip files in a directory.  For now, I'm assuming it's just a single directory without sub-directories.  It's very tempting to do something like this:

`du -scb /my/dir/*.gz|tail -n 1`

However, I have a TON of files.  Won't the `*.gz` expand to some sort of overflow condition?  Is there a faster, safer way to check this number?

Comment: What you have seems fine. Any decent implementation would support 64-bit files (larger than 2GB, I mean), and thus 64-bit totals too.

Comment: @Chris I think he's worried about exceeding the command line length limit. On most Linux systems it's pretty huge (128kB, if I remember right) but on some *nixes it's pretty small (I think on Solaris it's something like 255 bytes).

Comment: The command line length limit is my concern.  Is there a way to set and get that value from bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works and is "safe":

```
(find . -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 stat -c '%s' |
  tr '\n' '+'; echo 0) |
  bc
```

How it works:

- First, use `find` to find the '.gz' files. Print them with nul-separators, so we can deal with weird filenames.
- `xargs` will break up the groups of filenames into manageable chunks. Give those filenames to `stat -c '%s'` to get the sizes in bytes (thanks @Fritschy).
- `tr` converts the newlines to `+`. The echo adds one extra 0 at the end plus a newline. This is so we don't end up with a dangling plus sign, and `bc` needs a newline at the end of its input.
- Feed the huge sum into bc.

Comment: Nice one, check `stat(1)`, which can stat a file and print info according to a given format.

Comment: @Fritschy: thanks, I didn't know about `stat(1)`. Incorporated into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $(( $(find . -type f -name '*.gz' -printf '%s+') 0 ))
```

If you need *huge* values, change `'%s+'` to `'%s+0'` and change the `$(( ... 0 ))` to `... | bc`

**Edit**: For even larger values, you might want to use `%k` instead of `%s`, giving you kilobytes. Since the integer might overflow.

Since we are only using built-ins in bash, I'm not sure if the argument-length of executables are problem.